# Erase first instance of a vowel

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, replace, splice

I'm trying to write a program that removes the **first instance** of each vowel from a string.

"the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
becomes
"th quck brwn fox jumps over the lzy dog"

This is what my code looked like before (Comments on the next one)

```
str = "the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
letters = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']
i = 0
j = 0

strArr = str.split('') // converts word to string
vowel = letters[i]

// replaceVowel = str.replace(letters.indexOf(i), '');

while (i < str.length || j == 5)
if (strArr[i] == letters[j] ) {
    console.log('I found ' + letters[j])
    i = 0 
    j++
}

    else if (strArr[i] !== letters[j]){
        i++
}

strArr.join()
console.log(str);
```

My idea is to convert the string into an array with `split`, then compare the index of the string with the letters array [aeiou] and check for the first vowel.
The first 'a' gets replaced with whitespace and then it checks for the next vowel ('e').
This occurs until j=5 as that's when the loop would exit after checking for 'u'

I then changed up my code as so:

```
str = "the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
letters = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']
index = 0
j = 0

strArr = str.split('') // converts word to string
vowel = letters[index]

while (index < strArr.length && j !== 5)
// Where j references the vowels
if (strArr[index] == letters[j]) {
    strArr.splice(index, '')
    index = 0
    j++
    // j++ to cycle through vowels after the first
    // instance has been repaced
}

else if (strArr[index] !== letters[j]){
    index++
    // Cycle through the string until you find a vowel
}

else if (strArr[index] == str.length && j!== 6) {
    index = 0
    j++
    // If you hit the end of the string and couldn't find
    // a vowel, move onto the next one
    }
    

strArr.join()
console.log(str);
```

Nothing happens when I run it.
I am wondering if there is a flaw in my logic?

If there is also an easier way to do this please do inform me.

Your guidance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: FWIW your expected results is wrong as `quick` has two vowels `u` and `i`

Comment: Should all the `o` disappear or only the first `o` character that is encountered? The question is quite unclear - given the odd solution you accepted.

Comment: Please read my comments on the provided answers.

Comment: Can you explain why the **second** `u` is expected to be removed and not the **first** `u` in `quck`??

Comment: That was a mistake thanks for bringing this to attention!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the string by a space, then `map` through the array.

To remove the vowel, convert the string into an array, and use `findIndex` to find the first character which `vowels` includes. Then, remove that item.

```js
const str = `the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog`
const vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']
const result = str.split(' ').map(e => {
  const arr = [...e]
  return arr.splice(arr.findIndex(c => vowels.includes(c)), 1), arr.join('')
})
console.log(result.join(' '))
```

Comment: Thanks! I will be sure to remember this. Happy New Year!

Comment: OP asked for the ***first instance***, yet your answer removes i.e: the character `o` from everywhere. Also that example seems overly complicated for such a simple task - easily achievable by `.replace()`

Comment: your answer is wrong. Read again the question requirements and the sample output.

Answer (score 3):

I misunderstood the question to begin with but here is an example that simply iterates over an array of vowels and slices the first of each from the result string using [`String#indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) to find the index and [`String#slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) to cut around it.

```js
const str = 'the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog';

let result = str;
for (const vowel of ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']) {
  const vowelIndex = result.indexOf(vowel);
  result = result.slice(0, vowelIndex) + result.slice(vowelIndex + 1);
}

console.log(result);
// th qck brwn fox jumps over the lzy dog
```

An alternate solution is to iterate over each character of the string and check it against a `Set` of vowels removing the vowel if found, otherwise adding the character to the result string. Here using a ternary against [`Set.delete()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/delete) which returns true if the value was in the Set, otherwise false.

```js
const str = 'the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog';

const vowels = new Set(['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']);

let result = '';
for (const char of str) {
  result += vowels.delete(char) ? '' : char;
}

console.log(result);
// th qck brwn fox jumps over the lzy dog
```

##### Original answer

My original answer assumed you were looking to remove the first vowel from each word (as the accepted answer does). You can achieve this with a single `replace()` call using RegExp. (note this leaves the only `i` in `quick` since `u` is the first vowel in that word).

```js
const str = 'the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog';
const result = str.replace(/(\b[^aeiou]*)[aeiou](\w*\b)/gi, '$1$2');

console.log(result);
// th qick brwn fx jmps ver th lzy dg
```

Comment: Nice. Still not 100% since the illogical  "inverted `u` output" but at least pretty close and matches the requirement of both the title and question description.

Comment: Yeah, I can't account for the `u` issue without making up some logic. Thanks for setting me straight.

Answer (score 2):

There were some answers already here, this is an alternative approach:

```js
function getIndex(string, expression) {
    let position = expression.exec(string);
    if (position === null) return null;
    return position.index;
}

function getVowelIndex(string) {
    return getIndex(string, /[aeiou]/i);
}

let testCases = [
    "Something has gone wrong",
    "Or not",
    "Breaking news",
    "pfft!",
    "brkn leg",
    "I can't dance"
];

for (let testCase of testCases) {
    console.log(testCase + ": ", getVowelIndex(testCase));
}
```

Using `.exec()` we can get the index.

Now, let's remove it:

```js
function getIndex(string, expression) {
    let position = expression.exec(string);
    if (position === null) return null;
    return position.index;
}

function getVowelIndex(string) {
    return getIndex(string, /[aeiou]/i);
}

let testCases = [
    "Something has gone wrong",
    "Or not",
    "Breaking news",
    "pfft!",
    "brkn leg",
    "I can't dance"
];

for (let testCase of testCases) {
    let result = testCase;
    let position = getVowelIndex(testCase);
    if (position !== null) result = result.substring(0, position) + result.substring(position + 1);
    console.log(testCase + ": ", result);
}
```